# You don’t have permission to write to the folder that the file “ostream” is in

Tags: c++, xcode, popup, xcode11, ostream

I had an error while editing a C++ file and Xcode put out a suggestion I clicked fix and I've been getting this pop up every time I try to run ANY file or project. More than that that I can't uninstall Xcode because the pop up is not allowing me to quit the application and a computer restart is also being interrupted by Xcode's refusal to quit.[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Force-quitting Xcode sufficed for me. 
Instructions here: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201276
After reopening the project, the problem was gone.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution I'm not sure if its the best one but I just saved my files externally deleted the project where the error occurred and the error stopped showing up.

Then I redownloaded the project to my machine. 
I hope that helps if anyone runs into this problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to perferences->locations and delete the DerivedData folder
   [image: picture showing data]

2. Force close Xcode